# Java: How to reverse string based on non alphabetic delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, reverse

How to reverse string based on non alphabetic delimiters? I suspect my regex may be the problem.

```
String fileContent = "Joe'); MAKE TEST random;--";
String[] splitWords = fileContent.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : splitWords) {
    int idx = fileContent.indexOf(word, stringBuilder.length());
    String delim = fileContent.substring(stringBuilder.length(), idx);
    stringBuilder.append(delim);

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
    stringBuilder.append(output);
}
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

Current output: `'eoJ); EKAM TSET modnar`

Desired output: `eoJ'); EKAM TSET modnar;--`

Comment: Your testcase ends with a delimiter. Hence last ;-- is not appended.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for this. It seems you want to reverse characters that are only alphabets or digits.
Then you could do this way - get the start and end indices of the character array where you find the character to be a letter or digit and then reverse in place. Then return a new String with the characters reversed in place.

```
private static void reverseWords(char[] c) {
    int start = 0, end = c.length;
    while ( start < end ) {
      int pre = start;
      while ( start < c.length && Character.isLetterOrDigit(c[start]) ) 
        start++;
      if ( pre < start ) 
         reverseWord(c, pre, start-1);
      start++;  
    }
  }

  private static void reverseWord(char[] c, int start, int end) {
    while ( start < end ) {
      char temp = c[start];
      c[start] = c[end];
       c[end]  = temp;
      start++;
      end--;
    }
  }
```

You can test this code [here](https://repl.it/repls/VoluminousDeliriousIntroductory)

Answer (score 1):

You may match and reverse only chunks of 1+ letters (with a simple `\p{L}+` pattern) and keep the rest as is:

```
String s = "Joe'); MAKE TEST random;--";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String replacement = new StringBuilder(m.group()).reverse().toString();
    m.appendReplacement(result, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString()); // => eoJ'); EKAM TSET modnar;--
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/E9Xq6D).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works with two changes:

1. Replace the pattern
2. Test for trailing delimiter

String fileContent = "Joe'); MAKE TEST random;--";
 String[] splitWords = fileContent.split("\W"); // W is non word character or 
   I forgot

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : splitWords) {
    int idx = fileContent.indexOf(word, stringBuilder.length());
    String delim = fileContent.substring(stringBuilder.length(), idx);
    stringBuilder.append(delim);

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
    stringBuilder.append(output);
}
// did we have trailing delimiter ?
if(fileContent.length()!=stringBuilder.length())
{ //append remaining
    stringBuilder.append(fileContent.substring(stringBuilder.length()));
}
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Im struggling with styling this snippet